# to intersect two select queries in ms access without duplicate values in the result

Tags: database, ms-access

to intersect two select queries in ms access.
both queries refers to the same table.
for example,

```
select * from table1 where col1=ans1 intersect select * from table1 where col1=ans2
```

This query wont work in ms access.
I want my result without duplication..
give me the example code also.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this-

```
select * from table1 where col1=ans1 and col2=ans2
```

Comment: both where condition should have col1. you have given the condition one for col1 and another for col2. please provide me some other query. thanks.

Comment: then it would return no result because one single column cannot have more than one value for a single record.

Comment: or if you want to get the records with column **col1** with value **ans1** or **ans2** then use the following-

`where col1=ans1 or col1=ans2`

Comment: i want the intersection of both the selection.but this gives me all the selection of both condition.suggest me another query please.

Comment: Intersection means the common part that satisfies both condition. That's why I used `and`.